# Pricing of compounded swaps

Tags: risk-neutral-measure, interest-rate-swap, forward-rate, compounding

As far as I understand, a compounded swap rolls up individual payments into one final payment which becomes:
$$
V(t_n) = N \prod_{i = 0}^{n-1}(1 + d_i L_i)-N
$$

where $d_i$ is the day fraction for period $t_i$ to $t_{i+1}$ and $L_i$ is the index for the same period and where $N$ is deducted at the end because we assume no exchange of notional.

Now, to value this we need to calculate the expectation of $V(T)$ under some appropriate numéraire and measure, but we are dealing with products of various $L_i$'s which are, in general, not mutually independent, so it's not a simple matter of replacing with them forwards.

How is this then done? An internet search only revealed simple formulas using forwards. A good reference text would be welcome.

**Add 1**

Following suggestions in the comments, if I use the adjusted forward numéraire with maturity equal to the payment date $t_n$ and using $P(t_i, t_{i+1}) = \frac{1}{1 + d(t_i,t_{i+1}) L(t, t_{i+1})}$, then I get:
$$
V(t) = P(t, t_n) \Bbb{E}^{Q^{t_n}} [V(t_n)|F_t] 
     = N P(t, t_n) \left(\Bbb{E}^{Q^{t_n}} \left[\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{P(t_i, t_{i+1})} | F_t \right]-1\right)
$$

but I'm not sure that this gets me anywhere.

Comment: Check out "A quant perspective on IBOR fallback proposals" by M. Henrard. In Section 5.2 he refers to Th. 2.4 of _Interest Rate Modelling in the Multi-curve Framework_ by the same author, where he proves a formula for the case of a daily rate $r_i$. See also Section 5.4, option 4, of the same paper where he derives a formula very close to your case using nested conditional expectations, and coming up with a multiplicative convexity adjustment based on a 1F HJM Gaussian model.

Comment: Write the Libors in terms of bonds, then the product can be simplified.

Comment: _[Note: my comment refers to the case of overnight rates and is related to incoming SOFR-related changes, where this kind of compounded rates are common]_

Comment: __Hint:__ 1. Write the price as zc bond (for discount) multiplied by an expectation under the forward measure (of the payment date) 2. Write the compounding factor in terms inverse of ZC bonds: $1 + d L(T, T + d) = \frac{1}{P(T, T + d)}$ and 3. Use conditional exportations inside the expectation. If you are stuck after this, we might be able to help here.

Comment: @byouness Thank you for your hints but, alas, I didn't get far.

Comment: No prblm, I posted an answer. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 3):

Let us start from your last equation, and focus specifically on the expectation. Assuming that the end date of each period is the start period of the next, the idea is to simplify it using conditional expectations.

Since $t < t_{n-2}$, we can write using the tower property of conditional expectations:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Bbb{E}_{t}^{Q^{t_n}} \left[\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{P(t_i, t_{i+1})} \right]
&= \Bbb{E}_{t}^{Q^{t_n}} \left[\prod_{i=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{P(t_i, t_{i+1})} \times \frac{1}{P(t_{n-1}, t_{n})} \right]\\
&= \Bbb{E}_{t}^{Q^{t_n}} \left[ \Bbb{E}_{t_{n-2}}^{Q^{t_n}} \left[  \underbrace{\prod_{i=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{P(t_i, t_{i+1})}}_{\mathcal{F}_{t_{n-2}}-\text{measurable}} \times \frac{1}{P(t_{n-1}, t_{n})} \right] \right]\\
&= \Bbb{E}_{t}^{Q^{t_n}} \left[\prod_{i=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{P(t_i, t_{i+1})}\times \Bbb{E}_{t_{n-2}}^{Q^{t_n}} \left[ \underbrace{\frac{P(t_{n-1}, t_{n-1})}{P(t_{n-1}, t_{n})}}_{\mathbb{Q}^{t_n}\text{martingale}} \right]\right]\\
&= \Bbb{E}_{t}^{Q^{t_n}} \left[\prod_{i=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{P(t_i, t_{i+1})}\times \frac{P(t_{n-2}, t_{n-1})}{P(t_{n-2}, t_{n})} \right]\\
\end{aligned}
$$

We can see that the product is getting smaller, since the term $P(t_{n-2}, t_{n-1})$ that appeared in the numerator will simplify with the the last term of the product.
$$
\Bbb{E}_{t}^{Q^{t_n}} \left[\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{P(t_i, t_{i+1})} \right]
= \Bbb{E}_{t}^{Q^{t_n}} \left[\prod_{i=0}^{n-3} \frac{1}{P(t_i, t_{i+1})}\times \frac{1}{P(t_{n-2}, t_{n})} \right]
$$
By repeating this operation, the product disappears (assuming that at pricing date $t$, the swap didn't start yet, i.e.: $t < t_0$), and you get:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Bbb{E}_{t}^{Q^{t_n}} \left[\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{P(t_i, t_{i+1})} \right]
&= \Bbb{E}_{t}^{Q^{t_n}} \left[\frac{P(t_0, t_0)}{P(t_{0}, t_{n})} \right]\\
&= \frac{P(t, t_0)}{P(t, t_n)}\\
\end{aligned}
$$

This ratio can also be written as a product of capitalization factors using Libor forwards as follows:
$$
\frac{P(t, t_0)}{P(t, t_n)} = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{P(t, t_i)}{P(t, t_{i+1})} = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} 1 + d(t_i, t_{i+1}) L(t, t_i, t_{i+1})
$$

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer. I am not sure, however, I understand the steps in the first equation. It seems that they assume that $P(t_{n-2},t_{n-1}) P(t_{n-1},t_{n}) = P(t_{n-2},t_{n})$, but I don't see why this has to be the case. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I simply used the fact that the expectation of $\frac{P(t, t_{n-1})}{P(t, t_n)}$ under $\mathbb{Q}^{t_n}$, conditional on $\mathcal{F}_{t_{n-2}}$ is $\frac{P(t_{n-2}, t_{n-1})}{P(t_{n-2}, t_n)}$. In other words, $\left(\frac{P(t, t_{n-1})}{P(t, t_n)}\right)_t$ is a $\mathbb{Q}^{t_n}$-martingale. I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Yes, that step I understand; it's the first one I don't quite follow: how did $\frac{1}{P(t_{n-1},t_n)}$ became an expectation of itself conditional on $F_{t_{n-2}}$? And as mentioned in my first comment above, the results of step 1 and step 2 seem to imply that borrowing for, say, 3 months twice in a row is the same as borrowing once for 6 months and we know that this is not the case as there is a basis between 3M and 6M rates. Thank you

Comment: Ah okay, its simply the tower property of conditional expectations, since $t < t_{n-2}$, you can write: $\mathbb{E}_t [ AB ] = \mathbb{E}_t \left[ \mathbb{E}_{t_{n-2}} [ AB] \right]$. Next, if $A$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t_{n-2}}$-measurable then : $\mathbb{E}_t [ AB ] = \mathbb{E}_t \left[ A \mathbb{E}_{t_{n-2}} [ B] \right]$. I will clarify in my answer.

Comment: I hope everything is clear now ;)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. I am afraid, however, that there is a point that remains unclear to me and it actually relates to the original step 2 that I said I understand in my previous comment. :)  You state that $1/P(t_{n-1},t_{n})$ is a $Q^{t_n}$ martingale, but this measure is associated with $P(t, t_{n})$ numéraire, not $P(t_{n-1},t_{n})$. How do we account for this difference? Thank you

Comment: $(P(s, t_n))_s>0$ is the numéraire, so the expectation of $\frac{X(T)}{P(T, t_n)}$ (with $T > t$) under the associated measure (conditional to $\mathcal{F}_t$) is equal to $\frac{X(t)}{P(t, t_n)}$. This is what is written with $T = t_{n-1}$ and $X(s) = P(s, t_{n-1})$.

Comment: What if $X(T)=1$? Do we also have that $1/P(t_{n-1}, t_n)$ is a martingale under $Q^{t_n}$ measure? Do we not then get $\Bbb{E}^{t_n}_{t_{n-2}}[1/P(t_{n-1}, t_n)] = 1/P(t_{n-2}, t_n)$?

Comment: You can't just put anything in $X$. it must be a **self financed asset**, so $X(T) = 1$ doesn't work.
1 (or any constant for that matter) is a martingale under the T-forward measure, but $(\frac{1}{P(s, T)})_s$ is not.

Comment: Well, $1 is an asset :) and if interest rates are negative then I wouldn't put it into a bank account either. :)

Comment: The only case where this is valid is the case where rates are constant  and = 0. Otherwise, if 1 was a tradeable asset, then there is an obvious arbitrage opportunity by combining this asset =1 with a zero coupon bond in a portfolio... in any case, this is a separate subject, and we are diverging a bit from the original question :)

Comment: Thank you one again for taking your time to explain all the steps. The calculation is now clear. I still have a question on the interpretation of the result shown in my first comment above, i.e. that $P(t_{n-2},t_{n-1})P(t_{n-1},t_{n}) = P(t_{n-2},t_{n})$. As mentioned, it seems to imply that borrowing for, say, 3M twice in a row is the same as borrowing once for 6M, but we know that this is not the case due to the credit risk. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome :) the level of credit risk is determined by the curve that you will use for this pricing. Let's take a simple example to illustrate, where the 3M Libor is compounded every 3 months but paid only semi-annualy. The formula we reached will be computed using the 3M curve, not the 6M curve. While the discounting zero-coupon, outside the expectation in your question, will be computed using a different curve... I hope this clarifies it.

Comment: Not quite, I'm afraid. ) Let's introduce some additional notation to the previous calculation and denote by $P(t, t+\tau;\tau)$ a discounting zero-coupon bond price at time $t$ and maturity $t+\tau$ constructed from $\tau$-tenor curve, e.g. $\tau = 3M$. Then, we seem to have that $P(t,t+3M; 3M)P(t+3M,t+6M; 3M)=P(t,t+6M;6M)$, but this doesn't hold sine there is a basis between 3M and 6M curve.

Comment: (cont.) We might also need to make this tenor dependence explicit in our numéraire and associated measure. Thus, we began the calculation using $P(t,t+T;T)$ as a numéraire , but then we might be unwittingly switch to something else in the nested expectations.

Comment: I'd suggest we close this question as I believe it was answered. Then open a new one with your new question. Thanks.

Comment: In my answer, I never do: $P(t,t+3M;3M)P(t+3M,t+6M;3M)=P(t,t+6M;6M)$, but $P_t(t,t+3M;3M)P_t(t+3M,t+6M;3M)=P_t(t,t+6M;3M)$. That's what I meant by saying the level of credit risk is determined by the curve. We will not actually borrow for 6M, but for 3M, then 3M, but computing the product of the two fwds is the same as computing the 6M fwd mathematically... If it is still unclear please open a new question. Best regards.

Comment: But there is no such thing as a $P(t,t+6M;3M)$, i.e. there is no zero-coupon bond that matures in $6M$ but pays the rate derived from the $3M$ curve; if it matures in $6M$, it should be derived from $6M$ curve. I will raise another question on this point. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Exactly my point. It's just a way to price the compounding swap. It is not a real zc bond maturing in 6M but computed on the 3M curve.

Instead of computing 2 forward zc bonds on the 3M curve and doing the multiplication, you could compute a 6M zc bond on the 3M curve, and you will get the same result: $P_t(t,t+3M;3M)P_t(t+3M,t+6M;3M)=P_t(t,t+6M;3M)$.

Please accept the answer if it answered your original question, and do not hesitate to raise a new one on this topic if it is still unclear. Thanks!

Comment: But $P(t,t+6M; 3M)$ has to be a tradable instrument, and it's not. I am not sure I can close the original question just yet because of this point, but I am happy to open a new one specifically on this point and then come back here once it's clarified.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't see what the problem is.... It is an auto-financed portfolio that you can build dynamically from the 3M ZC: buy one ZC at t with maturity date $t + 3M$, then use the proceeds at $t + 3M$ to buy ZC with maturity date $t + 6M$. I think I can't help anymore if there is some unclarity left. So, if that's the case please open a new question. Best.